# Seams for use in cloth model

Tags: texturing, uv

I have found a conflict in how I want to UV unwrap my model for cloth modeling:

For material patches, it seems natural to make use of the seams the real thing would have (easier to paint the texture correctly).

For making seams look like seams I need to be able to paint over the real seam, making it hard if I use the real seam as UV seam.

How are such cases usually handled?

Answer (score 3):

You can use two UV maps. One UV map laid out how ever is best for your model with the main texture. Then a second UV map unwrapped so the cloth seams come out better for painting. 
[image: Uv Maps]

You can unwrap your model with UV seams and all, make a second UV map then mark all new UV seams and unwrap again.

Here is an old blender nerd [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xm0WRbxDZ1U) explaining the process. (for people that like video tutorials)

To use your two textures, and two UV maps in cycles, all you need are two *UV Map* nodes and two *Image Texture* nodes. Mix the two images together based on the "seams" image's alpha. The image below is a full node setup for using two image and two UV maps.
[image: cycles nodes]

Answer (score 3):

Using a texture with stencil mapping makes it easy to paint physical seams where you want them, regardless of where the uv seams are.

[image]

I gave more details about stencil painting [in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9064/can-project-paint-be-used-with-cycles/9069#9069)