# Making folds and sewing cloths

Tags: cloth-simulation, shape-keys

Blender Stack Exchange users!

I'm a newbie when it comes to 3D and Blender, and would greatly appreciate your help. I'm also new to Stack Exchange, and it appears that I can't post as many links as I need to, so I'm going to merge all of the relevant pictures below. Sorry for the inconvenience.

I wanted to make a kind of a long, simple-cut folk shirt with shoulder insets and pleating around the neck (1).

Following some tutorials on cloth sewing and creating cloth folds, I have made a set of planes that are connected with bridge edge loops, and wanted to start working on the folds of the neck-hole. I have managed to grab every other vertex on the edge of the right inset (group 'right-shoulder'), scale the group down on X-axis and create a shape-key (2).

For some reason, I can't seem to perform the same operation on the edge of the left inset (3). At first I thought it might have something to do with my pivot point and/or proportional editing settings, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

To make matters worse, the folds shape-key that I managed to create for the right inset doesn't show up when I run the cloth simulation. Different planes get sewn together though. I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Don't know if it's relevant, but I'm using Blender 2.71 and Windows 8.

Relevant pictures:
[image: Relevant pictures]

Comment: Have you thought about using just a texture (not a separate meshes) for creating this kind of ornaments? You may use similar method like in here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61396/how-to-create-stitching-by-texturing

Comment: Thanks, I think it would be a good way to go if I were creating a model for a complex scene, but my aim was to do painting studies of the folds affected by different light settings, so I would really rather try and simulate it with physics to get a more detailed look. 
Since the OP I've reworked the model (1), succesfully added shape keys to the neckhole-edges (2) and inserted the shape keys into the keyframe. Still, the cloth simulation is unaffected by the shape keys (3a, b), as if the shape keys were to weak to keep the cloth gathered like I want it to be. http://i.imgur.com/36plL2L.jpg