# How to make seams indent like in upholstery?

Tags: texturing

I've been working on some sofa and chair modelling and want seams to indent a little bit. Like this:

[image]

Who can help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I downvoted this question, because it resembles a [tutorial request and is off-topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/30849). Please show your research and condense your problem to a narrower area than *Who can help me out here?*.

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61396/how-to-create-stitching-by-texturing

Comment: @Leander are you always this rude? I've been here since less than hour, for god sake.

Comment: I apologize, if I was rude. I didn't mean to be rude. Feel free to correct my phrasing, as a none native speaker I may not notice some connotations. (Downvoting a question isn't a personal assertion against the asker.) If you're new I suggest you take the [tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [asking section](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/asking) of the help center.

Comment: @Leander apologies accepted. I've been struggling to get the problem fixed and trying different routes without a satisfying result. I followed the route of one of Blender Guru's tutorials but the result did not work out. Maybe my question was cutting corners. The process of learning can be frustrating sometimes.

Comment: You can always edit your question to add more details. If the Blender Guru tutorial looks promising but you fail to reproduce certain steps, please show them. If you could add some steps of what you did, a screenshot of how it look and perhaps a screenshot of the tutorial result or a description of what you want it to look like, then it will be much easier for others to add an answer.

Comment: @Leander Thanks. I will take the time to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Just a noob here, but...

I've found that you can INSET an area of multiple faces - so maybe, select all the faces of the interior of the cushion, then do inset (I) and inset a tiny amount. Do this a second time, and you have an trio of edges around the full perimeter of where the seam is. You can then select the middle edge (first inset edge) usually with ALT-LMB clicking on the edge. You should then be able to GRAB and move that lower than the level of the cushion.

As for the wavy bits, that's another story.