# Is there a way to paint text onto a texture in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-painting

Recently I have been painting textures in Blender, and I am very satisfied with the results as far as standard painting goes, however I have not been able to find any way to easily add text to a texture.

Is this possible, and if not, what other workarounds are there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blender's painting tools are limited to simple brushes and textures. The easiest way would be to open the image in an image editor and add text to it.

You could open an image with text on it and use it as a [stencil texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9069/935) to paint it onto your mesh.

For a hacky workaround you could add a text object, convert to mesh, use a boolean modifier to cut it out of a plane, then position it in front of your object and join it to your mesh and paint through the hole. Then you can select the disconnected mesh and delete it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Best way to 'paint' text into a texture is to load up your text object in a new scene with a square camera(1024x1024) and work out the layout of your text in the camera view. Add a shadeless white material to your text, and set your World to black. Render to a single image, and then in your main scene with your painting, load up the new image as a brush mask texture. Set the mapping to Clip to avoid tiling, and check 'calculate alpha' to turn the black into transparency. In your tool bar, under Texture Mask, choose 'Stencil' and then you can use alt-mmb to move it, shift-alt-mmb to scale it, and ctrl-alt-mmb to rotate it.[image: text as stencil]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a better way than those already mentioned.

- Create a text object
- Convert to mesh
- Apply a new material to your new text mesh object
- Add an image texture to the color slot of your material
- Unwrap UV of the text mesh as a cub projection
- Scale, move and rotate your UV in the image where you want to paint
- Texture paint in the 3D view onto the text mesh object

This allows you to paint only the text onto the image without bleeding over the edges.  It also allows you to scale and place the UV onto a pre-existing texture.